# Indent an entire paragraph?

Tags: html, text, xhtml, indentation, paragraph

I have a code setup for a FAQ page like this:

```
<p><strong>This Is A Question</strong></p>
<p><strong>Answer.</strong> This is the content of the answer, and I am going to keep 
typing until it kicks to a new line.</p>
```

I do notice that when this displays via the browser the new line does not align up to the start of the Answer Content. Align as in from the left. I am also aware not to expect HTML to do such a thing, must question is. What are my options on coming across "indenting" this text per se?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's [a jsfiddle of your markup](http://jsfiddle.net/NyUYv/). The description of your problem isn't very clear. What exactly is it you'd like to see?

Comment: @Alex - Here is the updated jsfiddle of my mark-up. http://jsfiddle.net/NyUYv/1/ . Do you see now? The text goes under "Answer" and what I want to get it to do is have the actual content of the answer to indent no matter how long it is so each line starts under the start of the answer content. Instead of going all the way to the left under the word "Answer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [Nicole Sullivan's css `.media` element](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/), you can check out a [two column solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NyUYv/2/) update to your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
<p><strong>This Is A Question</strong></p>
<p><strong style="float:left">Answer.</strong> 
<div style="display:inline-table;float:right">This is the content of the answer, and I am going to keep typing until it kicks to a new line.</div></p>
```

Edit: Scratch that, it works in FF + IE, but not in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try negative padding in CSS for the div of your paragraph.
Usually work across webkit and gecko.